# Is it plausible to forget the cockpit unlocking code?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, accidents, pilots, cockpit

Is it plausible for a pilot inside the cockpit to be incapacitated and that at the same time the pilot locked outside simply doesn't remember the code or the procedure for entering the cockpit?

Comment: I would speculate that the answer here is the same as the answer to "Do you forget your banking PIN or the procedure for making a withdrawal?" -- People can forget ANYTHING (human memory is very unreliable), but we do tend to remember things that are important to us or that we do frequently - and presumably gaining entry to the cockpit is both important to a pilot and something they do frequently :)

Comment: @voretaq7 Maybe it is silly, but I reasoned that when there are two pilots during a flight and one is outside and needs to enter, he can always rely on the other, so it can be that he doesn't know the code...

Comment: That may not be a good assumption -- This was discussed a little bit [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/conversation/forgetting-cockpit-door-code) and basically there's no way for the person inside the cockpit to know if the one outside *really* forgot the entry procedures or if they're *saying* they forgot because someone has them at knifepoint trying to get one of the pilots to open the door. In that situation the safest course of action is to keep the door closed anyway…

Comment: Also related: [The answers here & on the duplicates](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13521/what-happens-when-a-pilot-is-incapacitated)

Comment: @voretaq7, the pilot outside the cockpit needs to knock "7500" so the pilot inside knows he's been hijacked. (3/4 in jest...)

Comment: @FreeMan [This also works](https://youtu.be/6ds6w7SkHyw).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code would also be shared among the purser and/ or the other flight attendants, so the answer is no. I believe however that they tend to keep the same code for a few days within the same crew to make remembering it easier.

Comment: Perhaps you might explain who sets the code, and whether it is tested (by someone else) after being shared by that person with (the) others?

Comment: From the press conference Lufthansa gave on March 26, or sounded like they all have the code ready to quote when they are being woke up at midnight. It sounded though as if the code was never or rarely changed, but I guess that was more a poor choice of words then the truth. The code must be changed every now and then.

Comment: @Maverick283 "Every now and then" may but refer to quite a long period. After all even a leaked code can be ovrerridden from within the cockpit.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I know hence a comment and know answer and I simply have no idea at all in which interval this code is changed.

Comment: Does it mean you need to re-learn 7-digit numbers again and again, knowing that probably you won't ever need them even once in your life?